# why Cranck-Nicolson scheme is always stable?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Given Cranck-Nicolson scheme:

$$\frac{u_{i}^{(k+1)} - u_{i}^{(k)}}{h_t}-\frac{c^2}{2}(\frac{u_{i-1}^{(k)}-2u_{i}^{(k)}+u_{i+1}^{(k)}}{h_{x}^{2}} +\frac{u_{i-1}^{(k+1)}-2u_{i}^{(k+1)}+u_{i+1}^{(k+1)}}{h_{x}^{2}}) =0$$

Is it possible to show that Cranck-Nicholson scheme is always stable with using Fourier analysis?

Comment: Do you know [von Neumann stability analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis)?

Comment: I don't know von Neumann? Is it based on Fourier analysis?

Comment: Have you read the linked wiki page? Are you familiar with this concept? Yes it is based on Fourier analysis. If you want to evaluate stability of PDE discretization schemes, I recommend that you learn this technique.